# Regression with -1,1 target range - Should we use a tanh activation in the last 1 unit dense layer?

Tags: regression, activation-function

Say in a regression problem the target range to be between [0,1] or [-1,1], and say the last layer of the network is as

```
xx = tf.layers.dense(inputs=xx, units=1, name='Prediction')
```

Should we use a `sigmoid` or `tanh` activation function after `xx` respectively to enforce the output of the 1 unit dense layer to be between [0,1] or [-1,1]?

To mention that most of the regression examples that I have seen they do not add an activation function after `xx`, and leave it to be open and take whatever value it ends up taking.

Comment: Forcing the output to be in the desired range (by using an appropriate activation) eases the task of the learning algorithm, and I would definitely recommend it.